# Sybase Ase 15 error on multiple recordsets and active transaction

Tags: vb6, sap-ase

We have very old VB6 applications connecting to a Sybase database. Today they are running fine using the Open Client 12 drivers via ODBC connecting to a Sybase ASE 15 servers.

There is a plan on upgrading to the OpenClient 15 drivers and with that version I'm getting this error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)'
>
> Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type.
>
> Change the cursor type, commit the transaction, or close one of the recordsets.

As I understand searching the internet, the problem is in the Cursors.

In the old drivers in the ODBC configuration manager there was a Performance Tab and we have the *Select Method* in cursor, but with the new drivers this tab is gone and all we got about cursors is a section in the *General* tab named *Cursor Behavior*, in there we have the option *Use Cursors* checked.

Here is a little code snippet where I can reproduce the problem. All help is appreciated.

```
  Dim conObj As ADODB.Connection
  Dim objRs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim objRs2 As ADODB.Recordset
  Set conObj = New ADODB.Connection
  conObj.ConnectionTimeout = 10
  conObj.CommandTimeout = 5
  conObj.Provider = "MSDASQL"
  conObj.Open "DSN=cdbur32;UID=***;PWD=***;Database=dbsait;WSID=Test;APP=Test"
  conObj.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  conObj.BeginTrans
  Set objRs = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set objRs.ActiveConnection = conObj
  objRs.Source = "select id_estatus_aplicacion from dbo.cat_sait_estatus_aplicaciones"
  objRs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly
  objRs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly
  objRs.Open
  objRs.MoveNext
  Debug.Print objRs("id_estatus_aplicacion")
  Set objRs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set objRs2.ActiveConnection = conObj
  objRs2.Source = "select * from dbo.cat_sait_estatus_aplicaciones"
  objRs2.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly
  objRs2.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly
  objRs2.Open 'error here
  objRs.MoveNext
  Debug.Print objRs("id_estatus_aplicacion")
  conObj.RollbackTrans
  objRs.Close
  objRs2.Close
  Set conObj = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end the Sybase guys send us a new drivers and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Does changing lines

```
objRs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly
```

and

```
objRs2.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly
```

help?

Comment: All of them, in the end the Sybase guys send us a new drivers and that fixed the problem